# Is it ok to modify the jQuery library?

Tags: jquery, javascript-framework

In our project, we are locally using the jQuery minified version.
(we are using 3 versions - with noConflict)

Is it advisable to modify the jQuery library to suit my project needs?
Or for that matter, any jQuery libraries (ui, validator etc.)?

Comment: jQuery is open-source: you can modify it as you please. Of course, if you do, you have to replicate any changes in later versions and test.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using 3 jQuery libraries? Also, you can customize the jQuery UI library to fit your needs [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: Yeah, but first read licences.

Comment: you can override jquery in your local code so you don't actually *need* to rewrite jquery itself, if that's what you mean. Are you using 3 versions of jquery in the same document?

Comment: @War10ck - My application is quite a legacy app. We used jQuery 1.3. Then added 1.5 and 1.7 and now 1.9. I know I can customize jQuery UI download. I want to know if it is ok to modify the core jQuery UI library to suit my needs.

Comment: Are you allowed? Yes. Should you? Probably not, unless you are a jQuery Guru and have made significant code contributions to the library through the community. It's not advisable to modify the core jQuery library yourself because there is simply far too much that you can screw up or miss. I would be comfortable with recommending the route of extending or re-writing specific functions in a separate file though so you would include `jquery.1.3.min.js` followed by `jquery.1.3.webAppName.custom.min.js`

Answer (score 5):

If by *"modify the jQuery library"* you mean

- add a proper plugin
- or contribute to the project (discuss, make your change, then a pull request)

then it's OK.

If you really mean change the source and use that modified source then it's totally **not OK** : one of the best features of jQuery is the ability to deal with browser differences and to keep being usable and consistent, with new versions, when the browsers change. **Don't do that !**

Instead I'd advise you to

- speak with the community to see how your need could be covered (and to check it isn't)
- look at the ways jQuery can be, properly, [extended](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)